# How to get featured image of an ACF relation field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I run a Wordpress job board website, where I have a "Company" custom post with several ACF fields and a featured image, and a "Job" custom post always linked to a specific company.
When I submit a new "Job", I use an ACF relation field (linked to "Company" custom post) in order to get the company name and the company logo (logo = ACF image field).
Now, I would need also to retrieve the Company featured image in the job post, how can I do that?

Below is how I get the company logo image in a "Job" post:

```
<div class="single-logo-container">
     <?php
     $posts = get_field('job_company');
     if( $posts ): ?>
     <?php foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
     <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
     <?php
     $logo_image = get_field('logo_image');
     $size = 'thumbnail';
     if( $logo_image ) {
     echo wp_get_attachment_image( $logo_image, $size );
     } ?>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
   </div>
```

Thanks for your help!
Marc

Comment: If you have access to the company post id, then you can use `get_the_post_thumbnail()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: Works great, thanks disinfor !

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got this answer from @disinfor and it works great, I put the code below:

```
<?php
              global $post;
              $posts_2 = get_field('job_company');
              if( $posts_2 ): ?>
              <?php foreach( $posts_2 as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
              <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
              <div class="single-banner">
                <img class="single-banner-image" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ); ?>">
              <?php endforeach; ?>
              <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
 
function acf_set_featured_image( $value, $post_id, $field  ){
    
    if($value != ''){
        //Add the value which is the image ID to the _thumbnail_id meta data for the current post
        add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $value);
    }
 
    return $value;
}

// acf/update_value/name={$field_name} - filter for a specific field based on it's name
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=cursusfoto', 'acf_set_featured_image', 10, 3);
 
?>
```